# How to call multiple functions into one constant code structure?

Tags: php, algorithm, function

Here is my current code structure:

```
$i = 5; // the number of attempt which my app does to achieve success
for ( $i; $i > 0; $i-- ) {
    try {
        $bool = crawl_links(); 
        if ( $bool ) { 
            // function above is done successfully
            $i = 0;
        } else {
            // function above needs to try again
            throw new Exception('Fetch links is failed');
        }
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        // insert $e into Log.php file
    }  
}
```

Well I have five other function *(similar with `crawl_links()`)* that I want to call each of them in the same structure. Well I do that by copy-and-pasting code above several times and replace other functions whith `crawl_links()`. But it seems ugly.

Is there any better approach to handle that?

Comment: you can call the methods from there only and store the returns in an array.

Comment: @SayantanDas My current structure depends on the result of a function to continue. So I cannot call multiple functions at the same time in there.

Comment: put it in a function - you can pass on other functions as callback. something like `tryAgain(callable $callback, $description, $retryCount)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function:

```
function call_with_attempts(callable $function, $attempts = 5) {
  while ($attempts-- > 0) {
    try {
      if ($function()) {
        return;
      }
      throw new Exception("$function failed");
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      trigger_error($e->getMessage());
    }
  }
}

call_with_attempts(function () {
  // Custom function
  return true;
});

call_with_attempts('crawl_links', 3);
```

**Passing Parameters to the Function**

If you want to pass parameters to the function, use [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php):

```
function call_with_attempts(callable $function, array $params = [], $attempts = 5) {
  // ...
  if (call_user_func_array($function, $params)) {
    return;
  }
  // ...
}
```

Sample usage:

```
call_with_attempts(function () {
  echo var_export(func_get_args(), true), PHP_EOL;
  return true;
}, ['a', 'b']);
```

Sample output:

```
array (
  0 => 'a',
  1 => 'b',
)
```